# What does `span 1/ span 1` mean in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using Tailwind’s new CSS Grid feature. It has [Grid Column](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column) with values `span 1/span 1` for class `col-span-1`, `span 2/ span 2` for class `col-span-2` and so on until `span 12/span 12` for class `col-span-12`.

I am however unable to understand `span 1/ span 1` in practice. I can understand `1 / span 1`. I can also understand `span 1/ 3` but can’t seem to grasp `span 1/ span 1`.

Comment: `span 1/ span 1` is simply equal to `span 1` because start and end are equal: *If the start line is equal to the end line, remove the end line* (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-placement-errors)

Comment: Thank you for `If the start line is equal to the end line, remove the end line`. This makes it so much clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While asking the question, I was tinkering with the following CodePen and I seem to have found the solution.

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 bg-gray-300">
    <div class="bg-green-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black col-span-1">1</div>
    <div class="bg-indigo-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black">2</div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black">3</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black">4</div>
</div>
```

The above HTML assumes you have Tailwind CSS linked. It shows the following output -

[image: Col Span 1]

Notice, the `col-span-1` in `1`. `col-span-1` refers to `span 1 / span 1`.

Now let’s change the code to the following:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 bg-gray-300">
    <div class="bg-green-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black col-span-2">1</div>
    <div class="bg-indigo-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black">2</div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black">3</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500 text-white text-6xl flex items-center justify-center border-8 border-black">4</div>
</div>
```

`1` contains `col-span-2` which is `span 2 / span 2`. It makes it cover `2`‘s space as well.

The output looks as follows:

[image: Col Span 2]

If we put `col-span-4` in `1`, it won’t work as we have specified the Grid to be of Column 3 in the parent `div` with `grid-cols-3`. Other than that, `span` covers space from where it starts.

Comment: *If we put col-span-4 in 1, it won’t work* --> it will work and it will generate and implicit column to make your grid with 4 columns:https://jsfiddle.net/m8y2nszj/ .. look closely to the right edge to notice the gap and if you inspect the code you will see an extra empty column

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif, it does create an implicit grid. I saw this with the Firefox DevTools. The number increased to 5. Although, I didn’t notice any gap :)

Edit: Nevermind I increased rows from 4 to 6 & can clearly see 5 on the 2nd row :)

Answer (score 9):

Your accepted answer doesn't really explain what's going on. Temani Afif said in the comments, 'span 1 / span 1 is simply equal to span 1'. That is true, but it doesn't explain the purpose of Tailwind’s code, which is what your question seems to be asking.

So let's consider the `span 2 / span 2` example. This is the value of the `grid-column` property, which is just shorthand for the `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` properties. It could also be written like this:

```
grid-column-start: span 2;
grid-column-end: span 2;
```

The '[Grid Placement Conflict Handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-placement-errors)' section of the specs says:

> If the placement contains two spans, remove the one contributed by the end grid-placement property.

So that code, **when considered in isolation**, is equivalent to:

```
grid-column-start: span 2;
```

That works okay if you don't specify a start line for the grid item. But let's say you need to make the item start from the third line… You could set `grid-column-start` to `3`, but now you've overridden the previous value of `span 2`. What you're really wanting to say is this:

```
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: span 2;
```

The reverse is true if you want to set its position from the right edge of the grid. Then you might say:

```
grid-column-start: span 2;
grid-column-end: -3;
```

A utility framework like Tailwind can't possibly know which end you want to position the cell from, so it covers its bases and defines *both* up front:

```
grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
```

Now, you can overwrite either of these properties with an integer (representing position), or you can just leave it as, and the `grid-column-end` value is simply ignored.